# why "bson" librarye dosen't work in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, file, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, bson

I'm trying to read a bson file this is my code:

```
import bson
with open("D:/rl env/chat_log.bson",'rb') as f:
    datas = bson.decode_all(f.read())
```

note that **"D:/rl env/chat_log.bson"** is my file path.
i got below error:

AttributeError: module 'bson' has no attribute 'decode_all'

**I must mention that I didn't get any error when I ran this code in google colab.**

Comment: Sorry, but the error message gives a pretty clear answer, so I don't see why you're asking "why?". Note that you can inspect pretty much everything using `help(x)` or `dir(x)`, so you can check what e.g. a module contains. With that in mind, you may want to ask yourself what the difference between the two environments is (Python and/or library versions, I guess).

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thanks for your attention but my python and bson versions are the same in two environments.

Comment: Please provide the _whole_ backtrace! As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. I guess your own Python file is called bson.py in one of the two envs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `loads` method

```
with open("D:/rl env/chat_log.bson",'r') as f: 
    datas = bson.loads(f.read())
```

Comment: yes but I got AttributeError: module 'bson' has no attribute 'loads'. I've installed all the necessary packages.

Comment: Can you run `pip freeze` and share the bson version?

Comment: my bson version in jupyter notebook is 0.5.10 and it's the same as bson version in google colab env.

Answer (score 0):

`decode_all()` is part of the pymongo API, but not of the [bson package](https://pypi.org/project/bson/) that you might have installed. Both packages are exposing `bson` at top-level.

Have a look here: https://github.com/py-bson/bson/issues/41 and https://github.com/py-bson/bson/issues/102

Make sure you the right package is used by running

```
pip3 uninstall bson
pip3 install pymongo
```